# I wanted to create random English words with each letter uppercased, but I failed although I followed exact same code as instruction shows

Tags: dart, package

In Android Studio, I imported a package, and then I added english_words: ^4.0.0
which came out a message:"C:\Users\Miche\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in startup_name...                       521ms
Process finished with exit code 0".

In the main dart:
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wordPair = WordPair.random();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('wordPair.asPascalCase'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But the emulator came up like wordPair.asPascalCase exactly as child text.
Where am I wrong? Thank you! Please help me :)

Comment: Hello? .........

Comment: You provided the literal string `'wordPair.asPascalCase'` to your `Text` widget.  You probably meant to pass the *value* instead: `Text(wordPair.asPascalCase)` (note the lack of quotes).

Comment: Yes, I meant to pass the value. How can I pass the value instead of passing the text?

Comment: I told you how: remove the quotes.

Comment: Thanks! But it's not working. More errors. I followed the instruction of "Write your first app", so I don't think it is the problem. By the way, I don't know if this message " --no-color pub get" means the package I installed failed.

Comment: What are the other errors?  It is absolutely a problem that you put quotes around the object you want to print.  Quotes create string literals.

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'. This is what the instruction says :https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab. It added text().

Comment: It sounds like you removed the `Text()` part too.  Remove *just* the quotes instead, as I indicated in my original comment.  You are *not* copying the code from the codelab verbatim and are making transcription mistakes.

Comment: Oh my gosh, it works! Thank you very much!